# Objective-C –Setting network indicator to visible after application is launched

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate

Is it possible to set `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];` in `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Maybe because I'm using a Default.png ?

Comment: How do you think that your Default.png is interacting with it?

Comment: The thing is that if I turn it on it starts to spin AFTER Default.png disappears from the view. I want it to spin WHILE Default.png is displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it gets turned off as wcrane suggested but also make sure you don't have some other 3rd party library in your project that possibly does that. Also, try calling it after a delay of, say, 0.5s or something. E.g.

`[self performSelector:@selector(turnOnNetworkIndicator) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5]`

Comment: The thing is that if I turn it on it starts to spin AFTER Default.png disappears from the view. I want it to spin WHILE Default.png is displayed on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible :(
I'm not 100% sure but Default.png is shown only during your app loading. So your app 'entry point' application:didFinishLaunching is called after Default.png is removed from the screen. Again, not 100% sure but almost...

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, check if you turn it down at some place later.

Comment: Maybe because I'm using a Default.png ?